# Clojure use Java JsonPath

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to use https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath in Clojure

It looks straightforward from the README, especially since it uses static functions. So I replicated the example from the README:

```
(import '[com.jayway.jsonpath JsonPath Criteria Filter])


(JsonPath/parse "{\"a\":\"1\"}") ;; returns a com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext

(JsonPath/read (JsonPath/parse "{\"a\":\"1\"}") "$.a")
;; (.read (JsonPath/parse "{\"a\":\"1\"}") "$.a")
;; Exception ->
;; 1. Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
;; No matching method: read
;; I tried variations of the above line
;; for some reason this seems to want to take `this` as first parameter - I cannot
;; figure out why, and cannot seem to be able to pass a valid value
```

How can I call this Java static function from Clojure? Why does it want as `this`?

dependency: `[com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path "2.4.0"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the varargs with `Predicate` on [`read`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/blob/6c738c9aa2ca6023c6d8b4e63b9f43e7110bbb2e/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.java#L501).  On JVM-Level you *have to* pass those args as array.  With Java the compiler will take care of that.

E.g. this works:

```
user=> (import '[com.jayway.jsonpath JsonPath Criteria Filter Predicate])
#<Class@5a114a96 com.jayway.jsonpath.Predicate>
user=> (JsonPath/read "{\"a\":\"1\"}" "$.a" (into-array Predicate []))
"1"
```